# Struts2 : Model or Action? What about the Model-Driven class?

Tags: model-view-controller, model, struts2, action, model-driven

I'm not concerned about making a useful project under Struts2, only, but a well structured one, too. I have a bean called **Custormer**, in which there are necessary attributes and their getters and setters.. I wonder then where I should build the different manipulations of the **Custormer** bean, such as **Subscribe**, **Upgrade**, ... Should it be in the Model class or the Action class? Also, I don't understand exactly for what the **Model-Driven** class is needed.. Thank you a lot guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither, those likely belong in service classes–but it's impossible to tell from your description. What actually *happens* when a user subscribes? Upgrades?

Action classes should be essentially nothing more than glue between the web and business layers, marshaling data, handling success/error conditions from both layers, etc.

Model classes are just that–models of your business domain. The nature of those models can vary wildly between domains, design/architecture methodologies, etc. Where business functionality lies can vary just as wildly. Service layers, DDD, etc. may all handle such functionality.

It should *not*, however, be implemented *directly* by actions. Rather actions should delegate to a service layer, the models, etc. In other words, an action shouldn't directly update a database field to indicate a user has upgraded. The web layer just directs site users around.

`ModelDriven` is just an abstraction that says that instead of putting the action on the top of the value stack (e.g., form properties will be set on action properties), an instance of the *model* will be on the top of the stack (e.g., form properties will be set on the model instance).

Comment: Well, I've noticed in all the examples I've seen that they restrict the use of a Model class for attributes, getters and setters, but no other methods... And if I create a Service package in which I create classes which manipulate objects of different Model classes, how can I then call the methods defined in the Service classes? Because i have also remarked that we often match an Action to a Model, and so in the Action class there is an object of the Model classe ( User => UserAction )... What should we do then in case of Service package? I hope my questions are clear. Thank you again :)

Comment: @user1459961 You call service methods from actions or other services, in general.